Can the Shortest Edge Paths geometry node be used to grow a selection?
According to a thread on Blender Dev Talk, it's possible to use the shortest edge paths node to grow or shrink an existing selection:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/93909


My question is how would this be achieved exactly, what is the node setup?
Assuming a simple case where I have a single face selected -

I'd like to grow that selection to the surrounding faces by using the shortest edge paths node.

Please note that I'm only using faces as an example, it could be a point or edge selection also.
I'm quite interested in the method I mentioned above for the following reasons -

The commenter on Dev Talk mentions to avoid using the 'domain interpolation' method of expanding a selection which is usually recommended




Other methods I've tried don't very easily allow for masking of the expanding selection e.g only growing the selection to a percentage of surrounding faces.


My hope is that the edge cost feature of the shortest edge paths node will allow for a simple way to 'mask' the expanding selection.
Perhaps there is some performance benefit to using this approach also?
My ultimate use case is to create a simulation zone that expands a selection of faces in an organic / randomised way e.g a spread solver for ice forming across a mesh.
Any pointers are appreciated!

What does "selection" mean here? A boolean value to set a material? I have no idea how this should work with the Shortest Edge Paths node because this node calculates paths between given start and end points. Maybe someone else knows. The problem is that you only have the "start point" (white face). The endpoints (green faces) are unknown. How do you want to calculate a path to destination "unknown"?  -- Your last sentence sounds like you want to do something similar to "find the neighboring faces of a given face". Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250307/107598

Thanks for your reply, ‘selection’ in this case would be a Boolean attribute with a value of 1. Could be on a face, vertex or edge (I was using face as an example). The way you characterised the goal is pretty much it - to find the neighbouring faces to an existing ‘selection’ of faces and then expand the selection to encompass those new faces. Also yes I wasn’t sure exactly how the shortest edge paths would help, but the person in the linked to thread seemed confident it was a possible solution.

R.e the post you linked to, that (domain interpolation) is a possible way to achieve the same thing, however the issue I’m facing with that solution is there’s no obvious way to ‘mask’ the expanded selection, e.g to only expand selection to a certain percentage of surrounding faces. Furthermore the dev talk thread I referred to explicitly states to avoid using that option, and instead use shortest edge paths (unfortunately they don’t elaborate on how that would be implemented in practice).

I think for an even growth of selection, using "Blur" node will be much easier. You'd use the shortest path for something more elaborate, e.g. grow the selection across short edges, or only horizontally, or according to some formula that you pass to the shortest path weight.
